# How do I create a form with checkboxes in slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I guess this goes to the fundamentals of rails. Is it possible for me to simple have a checkbox and a submit button without it being tied to a model?

I found that most Rails example out there are using `form_for` and this needs to be bound to a particular model. Can I just send a boolean parameter to a particular controller without having to be bound to a particular model? I just want to send a boolean value to a controller.

I am having trouble finding examples for this particular format, especially using slim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Controller

```
class MyController
  def create
    @flag = params[:flag]
  end
end
```

in View

```
= form_tag '/mycontroller', method: :post do
  = check_box_tag 'flag', true, @flag
  = submit_tag 'Save'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, use form_tag instead of form_for http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

So for your checkbox example you need

```
<%= form_tag('/posts/1', method: :put) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'accept'%>
  <%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```